# Html tags in xml (rss)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rss

Followed http://damieng.com/blog/2010/04/26/creating-rss-feeds-in-asp-net-mvc to create RSS for my blog. Everything fine except html tags in xml document. Typical problem:

```
&lt;br /&gt;
```

insted of

```
<br />
```

Normally I would use

```
@HtmlRaw()
```

or

```
MvcHtmlString()
```

But how can I fix it in XML document created with SyndicationFeed?

**Edit:**
Ok, I'm starting to think that my question is pointless.
Should I just leave my RSS as it is?

Comment: Unless your posts are fully valid XHTML, that behavior is correct and necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the XML element, you can wrap the text with your HTML in it in as a CDATA section:

```
<![CDATA[ 

   your html


]]>
```

I don't recommend doing that, however.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the text in side the CDATA

```
var xml= '<person><name><![CDATA[<h1>john smith</h1>]]></name></person>',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "name" );


$($title.text()).appendTo("body");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D2vUZ/8/)